# Customize Laravel auth Login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I need to customize the Login native code of the Laravel Authentication. I started by overrode some methods on `LoginController` such us `credentials` and `validateLogin` adding a field.
But I need to add some other checks, such us the possibility to join with an other table and other code, before to login the user but I didn't find solutions on internet.

I found some infos about the possibility to override the `attemptLogin` method or create a guard, but I didn't understand how do this.

Comment: Which Laravel authentication package are you using?

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu the native one explained here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Answer (score 0):

In you `LoginController` you can just override the `attemptLogin()` any other method in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait depending on where your custom logic will make sense:

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // add your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this, but how can I edit/customize the attemptLogin method? What I have to change?

Comment: just change the method logic

Comment: what return the code you removed? What I need to return to leave the login function that works? 
`return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        ); `

Comment: I think it just returns a boolean. You could just `dd()` and find out for yourself.